# Console tool for python type hint checking

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a project with type hints (Python 3.5.2). I would like to run the static checker to verify that the constraints specified in the type hints are being respected. What tools are available for this? I have been unable to find a reference in the [corresponding PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Comment: *"While the proposed typing module will contain some building blocks for runtime type checking -- in particular the get_type_hints() function -- third party packages would have to be developed to implement specific runtime type checking functionality, for example using decorators or metaclasses."* – The PEP explicitly doesn't define or recommend any particular tools, and neither can we. Personally I find PyCharm useful, but it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks, but I am looking for a console tool. Title edited.

Answer (score 8):

[Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) is probably what you're looking for. It's a console-based tool that can typecheck your Python code using PEP 484 type annotations. The reason why it isn't mentioned in PEP 484 is because there's no inherent reason why mypy would be the only possible typechecker out there -- Pycharm, for example, implements something similar also based on PEP 484 annotations.

Mypy is still under active development/beta mode and so you might run into the occasional bugs, but it's relatively stable.